# Making a responsive control in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controls, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive design like in Word. I used Toolbar and ToolbarSkin code and made changes to it. Now I don't know how to make it so it will check the priority of the control, and the lowest priority gets resized, while the control with the highest priority still shows full-size.
Code I changed in ToolbarSkin:

```
private void addNodesToToolBar() {
    final Responser toolbar = getSkinnable();
    double length = 0;
    if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        length = snapSize(toolbar.getHeight()) - snappedTopInset() - snappedBottomInset() + getSpacing();
    } else {
        length =  snapSize(toolbar.getWidth()) - snappedLeftInset() - snappedRightInset() + getSpacing();
    }

    // Is there overflow ?
    double x = 0;
    boolean hasOverflow = false;
    for (Node node : getSkinnable().getItems()) {
        if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            x += snapSize(node.prefHeight(-1)) + getSpacing();
        } else {
            x += snapSize(node.prefWidth(-1)) + getSpacing();
        }
        if (x > length) {
            hasOverflow = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hasOverflow) {
        if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            length -= snapSize(overflowMenu.prefHeight(-1));
        } else {
            length -= snapSize(overflowMenu.prefWidth(-1));
        }
       length -= getSpacing();
    }

    // Determine which node goes to the toolbar and which goes to the overflow.
    x = 0;
    overflowMenuItems.clear();
    box.getChildren().clear();
    for (Node node : getSkinnable().getItems()) {
        node.getStyleClass().remove("menu-item");
        node.getStyleClass().remove("custom-menu-item");
        if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            x += snapSize(node.prefHeight(-1)) + getSpacing();
        } else {
            x += snapSize(node.prefWidth(-1)) + getSpacing();
        }
        if (x <= length) {
            box.getChildren().add(node);
        } else {
            if (node.isFocused()) {
                if (!box.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                    Node last = engine.selectLast();
                    if (last != null) {
                        last.requestFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                   overflowMenu.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            if (node instanceof Separator) {
                overflowMenuItems.add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
            } else {
                CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(node);

                // RT-36455:
                // We can't be totally certain of all nodes, but for the
                // most common nodes we can check to see whether we should
                // hide the menu when the node is clicked on. The common
                // case is for TextField or Slider.
                // This list won't be exhaustive (there is no point really
                // considering the ListView case), but it should try to
                // include most common control types that find themselves
                // placed in menus.
                final String nodeType = node.getTypeSelector();
                switch (nodeType) {
                    case "Button":
                    case "Hyperlink":
                    case "Label":
                        customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(true);
                        break;
                    case "CheckBox":
                    case "ChoiceBox":
                    case "ColorPicker":
                    case "ComboBox":
                    case "DatePicker":
                    case "MenuButton":
                    case "PasswordField":
                    case "RadioButton":
                    case "ScrollBar":
                    case "ScrollPane":
                    case "Slider":
                    case "SplitMenuButton":
                    case "SplitPane":
                    case "TextArea":
                    case "TextField":
                    case "ToggleButton":
                    case "ToolBar":
                        customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
                        break;
                }

                overflowMenuItems.add(customMenuItem);



                box.getChildren().clear();
                setNameToButton(make,box.getParent().getId());
                box.getChildren().add(make);
               // overflowMenuItems.remove(overflowMenuItems.size()-1);

            }

        }

    }

    // Check if we overflowed.
    overflow = overflowMenuItems.size() > 0;
    if (!overflow && overflowMenu.isFocused()) {
        Node last = engine.selectLast();
        if (last != null) {
            last.requestFocus();
        }
    }
    overflowMenu.setVisible(overflow);
    overflowMenu.setManaged(overflow);

}
```

and:

```
@Override protected void layoutChildren(final double x,final double y,
                                        final double w, final double h) {
    final Responser toolbar = getSkinnable();

    if (toolbar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        if (snapSize(toolbar.getHeight()) != previousHeight || needsUpdate) {
            ((VBox)box).setSpacing(getSpacing());
            ((VBox)box).setAlignment(getBoxAlignment());
            previousHeight = snapSize(toolbar.getHeight());
            addNodesToToolBar();
        }
    } else {
        if (snapSize(toolbar.getWidth()) != previousWidth || needsUpdate) {
            ((HBox)box).setSpacing(getSpacing());
            ((HBox)box).setAlignment(getBoxAlignment());
            previousWidth = snapSize(toolbar.getWidth());
            addNodesToToolBar();
        }
    }
    needsUpdate = false;

    double toolbarWidth = w;
    double toolbarHeight = h;

    if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        toolbarHeight -= (overflow ? snapSize(overflowMenu.prefHeight(-1)) : 0);
    } else {
        toolbarWidth -= (overflow ? snapSize(overflowMenu.prefWidth(-1)) : 0);
    }

    box.resize(toolbarWidth, toolbarHeight);
    positionInArea(box, x, y,
            toolbarWidth, toolbarHeight, /*baseline ignored*/0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);

    // If popup menu is not null show the overflowControl
    if (overflow) {
        double overflowMenuWidth = snapSize(overflowMenu.prefWidth(-1));
        double overflowMenuHeight = snapSize(overflowMenu.prefHeight(-1));
        double overflowX = x;
        double overflowY = x;
        if (getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            // This is to prevent the overflow menu from moving when there
            // are no items in the toolbar.
            if (toolbarWidth == 0) {
                toolbarWidth = savedPrefWidth;
            }
            HPos pos = ((VBox)box).getAlignment().getHpos();
            if (HPos.LEFT.equals(pos)) {
                overflowX = x + Math.abs((toolbarWidth - overflowMenuWidth)/2);
            } else if (HPos.RIGHT.equals(pos)) {
                overflowX = (snapSize(toolbar.getWidth()) - snappedRightInset() - toolbarWidth) +
                        Math.abs((toolbarWidth - overflowMenuWidth)/2);
            } else {
                overflowX = x +
                        Math.abs((snapSize(toolbar.getWidth()) - (x) +
                                snappedRightInset() - overflowMenuWidth)/2);
            }
            overflowY = snapSize(toolbar.getHeight()) - overflowMenuHeight - y;
        } else {
            // This is to prevent the overflow menu from moving when there
            // are no items in the toolbar.
            if (toolbarHeight == 0) {
                toolbarHeight = savedPrefHeight;
            }
            VPos pos = ((HBox)box).getAlignment().getVpos();
            if (VPos.TOP.equals(pos)) {
                overflowY = y +
                        Math.abs((toolbarHeight - overflowMenuHeight)/2);
            } else if (VPos.BOTTOM.equals(pos)) {
                overflowY = (snapSize(toolbar.getHeight()) - snappedBottomInset() - toolbarHeight) +
                        Math.abs((toolbarHeight - overflowMenuHeight)/2);
            } else {
                overflowY = y + Math.abs((toolbarHeight - overflowMenuHeight)/2);
            }
            overflowX = snapSize(toolbar.getWidth()) - overflowMenuWidth - snappedRightInset();
        }
        overflowMenu.resize(overflowMenuWidth, overflowMenuHeight);
        positionInArea(overflowMenu, overflowX, overflowY, overflowMenuWidth, overflowMenuHeight, /*baseline ignored*/0,
                HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Also I don't know how can I implement so only one control will shrink at the time, not all of them.
Thank you for your help.